# Erro ao criar referência da classe e concatenar métodos em Swift

Tags: ios, swift, classes

Boa noite.

Tenho duas classes e criei uma instância fazendo referência da classe pai chamando seu método e o mesmo não roda e mostra a seguinte frase:

"swift expressions are not allowed at the top level"

PS: Já tentei de tudo, criei, recriei... estão todos num mesmo grupo no Xcode

O que pode ser?

Segue print

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce tem que colocar o seu código dentro de uma função/metodo ou dentro do viewDidLoad ou viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está colocando código para ser executado diretamente no top-level do arquivo, assim como faria em linguagens como Python e JavaScript.

Swift, assim como C, C++, Java, entre outras, só aceita execução de código dentro de funções. Ou seja, as linhas 7 e 8 de seu código devem estar dentro de uma função.

Como você está está programando para iOS, pode colocar em qualquer função do ciclo de vida do aplicativo, como, por exemplo, a viewDidLoad e a viewDidAppear.

Comment: Diga-se de passagem, no playground do xcode, funciona normalmente. Obrigado pela resposta.